# Long equation linebreak

Tags: equations

I am trying to write a long equation and I dont want it to go out of the page so im trying to make a linebreak. I've been looking around on how to do it but I cant get it to work for one of my equations

```
\begin{align*}
\delta_{c_{m}}& = \pm c_m \cdot \sqrt{(\frac{c_V \cdot \delta_{m_V}}{C_{Total}})^2 + (\frac{c_B \cdot \delta_{m_B}}{C_{Total}})^2 + (\frac{c_O \cdot \delta_{m_O}}{C_{Total}})^2 + (\frac{1,93 \cdot \delta_{V_T}}{C_{Total}})^2 + \\
&(\frac{\delta_{T_2}}{T_2-T_1})^2 + (\frac{\delta_{T_1}}{T_2-T_1})^2 + (\frac{\delta_{m_m}}{m_m})^2 + (\frac{\delta_{T_m}}{T_m-T_2})^2 + (\frac{\delta_{T_2}}{T_m-T_2})^2}
\end{align*}
```

can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't use empty lines in `align*`

Comment: Why not avoiding the square root? `\delta_{c_m}^2=c_m^2\cdot...`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your equation correctly, you like to have under square root a sume of nine terms. This can be broken into more lines:

[image]

However, it not looks very nice ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{showframe}% for show text borders

\begin{document}
\[
\delta_{c_{m}} = \pm c_m \sqrt{
                \begin{multlined}
    \left(\frac{c_V \delta_{m_V}}{C_{Total}}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{c_B \delta_{m_B}}{C_{Total}}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{c_O \delta_{m_O}}{C_{Total}}\right)^2
        \\
        + \left(\frac{1,93 \delta_{V_T}}{C_{Total}}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{\delta_{T_2}}{T_2-T_1}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{\delta_{T_1}}{T_2-T_1}\right)^2
        \\
        + \left(\frac{\delta_{m_m}}{m_m}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{\delta_{T_m}}{T_m-T_2}\right)^2
        + \left(\frac{\delta_{T_2}}{T_m-T_2}\right)^2
                \end{multlined}
                }
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to break lines is the `multline`, which splits equations, aligning first part to the left and other part to the right. Another handy one is `align`, which uses `&` to align multiple lines (in this example `-` and `\times` are aligned. `\nonumber` prevents equation numbering, otherwise occuring on each line of the `align` equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \ang{}
\usepackage{geometry}%layout

\geometry{
    left=25mm,%margins
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
    \text{UT+1} = (5^{h} + \frac{52^{m}}{60^{m}} + \frac{19^{s}}{3600^{s}}) - \frac{\ang{4.9;;}}{\ang{360}} \times 23.93446959^{h}\\
    - 24^{h} \times \frac{2457054.5^{d} - 2456921.5^{d}}{365.25636^{d}} + 24 + 1 =  21.80710218^{h} = 21^{h}48^{m}26^{s},
\end{multline}

\begin{align}
    \text{UT+1} = (5^{h} + \frac{52^{m}}{60^{m}} + \frac{19^{s}}{3600^{s}}) &- \frac{\ang{4.9;;}}{\ang{360}} \times 23.93446959^{h}\nonumber\\
    - 24^{h} &\times \frac{2457054.5^{d} - 2456921.5^{d}}{365.25636^{d}} + 24 + 1 =  21.80710218^{h} = 21^{h}48^{m}26^{s},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

**EDIT 1:**

another possibility is

```
\begin{align*}
\delta_{c_{m}}& = \pm c_m \cdot \sqrt{
\begin{gathered}
a + b + c  \\
+def + ghi + jkl \\
+xyz
\end{gathered}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

or even

```
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{
\begin{aligned}
a&+b    &   c&+d   &   e&+f\\
aaa&+bbb    &   ccc&+ddd   &   eee&+fff
\end{aligned}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Nicer `+` alignment:

```
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{
\begin{aligned}
a&+b        &   c&+d       &   e&+f\\
aaa&+bbb    &   ccc&+ddd   &   eee&+fff
\end{aligned}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: The edit 1 solution using `gathered` under the square root is very neat, but `\begin{pedantry}` you may want to correct the spacing of the + sign at the start of each row `\end{pedantry}`